# Python сохранение с бэкапами и лимитами

Tags: python

Уже сломал себе всю голову, пробрал сотни способов, вышел на какой-то очень сложный, но верю, что можно проще.

Логика какая? - Нужно сохранить файл следующим образом:

Имеем входные параметры filename и savelimit.
Укажем их:

```
filename = 'test'
savelimit = 3
```

Сохраняем несколько раз, имеем:

```
test
test-1
test-2
test-3
```

Окей, наш лимит **3** работает. Теперь сохраняем еще раз, должно получиться так:

```
test
test-2
test-3
test-4
```

И тд...

Comment: сохраняй без лимитов, а потом удаляй старые

Comment: посмотрите  как [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) устроен, а лучше не изобретать велосипед и готовое использовать типа [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/logrotate.8.html)